# connecting my custom widget to my screen manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to build an App using Python and kivy.
In my kv file I wanted to create a custom widget (MenuFloatLayout)
which can be referenced by the other screens. It is basically a Menu bar that is on every screen. This bar consists of several toggle buttons that are in their down state and disabled if you are currently on the screen this button is linked to.

This is referenced by:
state: "down" if root.manager.current == 'Screenname' else "normal"

The Problem is:
root.manager.current is not linked to the usual screen manager anymore,
because my custom widget is the root now.

Is there a work around?
Or is there a easier way to link the toggle buttons state to the screen the user is on?

I am new to programming and Python, I'm glad for any help or tips you can give me! Thanks!

The Python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class StartWindow(Screen):
    pass


class PortfolioOverview(Screen):
    pass


class Portfolio(Screen):
    pass


class Market(Screen):
    pass


class Economics(Screen):
    pass


class PortfolioTools(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("vigiles.kv")


class VigilesApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    VigilesApp().run()
```

And the kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    StartWindow:
    PortfolioOverview:
    Portfolio:
    Market:
    Economics:
    PortfolioTools:

<MenuFloatLayout@FloatLayout>:
    Label:
        text: "Portfolio"
        markup: True
        size_hint: 0.5, None
        height: 30
        pos_hint:{"top":1, "left":1}

    TextInput:
        text: "Search"
        multiline: False
        size_hint: 0.5, None
        height: 30
        pos_hint:{"top":1, "right":1}

    ScrollView:
        size_hint: None, None
        do_scroll_y: False
        do_scroll_x: True
        size: 500, 150

        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            size_hint_y: None

            ToggleButton:
                group: "pmenu"
                text: 'Overview'
                state: "down" if root.manager.current == 'poverview' else "normal"
                disabled: True if root.manager.current == 'poverview' else False
                background_disabled_down: "atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_pressed"
                disabled_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                on_release: app.root.current = "poverview"

            ToggleButton:
                group: "pmenu"
                text: 'Portfolio'
                state: "down" if root.manager.current == 'portfolio' else "normal"
                disabled: True if root.manager.current == 'portfolio' else False
                background_disabled_down: "atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_pressed"
                disabled_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                on_release: app.root.current = "portfolio"

            ToggleButton:
                group: "pmenu"
                text: 'Market'
                state: "down" if root.manager.current == 'market' else "normal"
                disabled: True if root.manager.current == 'market' else False
                background_disabled_down: "atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_pressed"
                disabled_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                on_release: app.root.current = "market"

            ToggleButton:
                group: "pmenu"
                text: 'Economics'
                state: "down" if root.manager.current == 'economics' else "normal"
                disabled: True if root.manager.current == 'economics' else False
                background_disabled_down: "atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_pressed"
                disabled_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                on_release: app.root.current = "economics"

            ToggleButton:
                group: "pmenu"
                text: 'Tools'
                state: "down" if root.manager.current == 'ptools' else "normal"
                disabled: True if root.manager.current == 'ptools' else False
                background_disabled_down: "atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_pressed"
                disabled_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                on_release: app.root.current = "ptools"


<StartWindow>:
    name: "start"
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
        color: 1, 1, 1, 0
        id: login_layout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [10,10,10,10]
        spacing: 30

        Label:
            text: 'some text'
            font_size: 32
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Label:
                text: 'Login'
                font_size: 18
                halign: 'left'
                text_size: root.width-20, 20
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1

            TextInput:
                id: login
                multiline:False
                font_size: 28

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: 'Password'
                halign: 'left'
                font_size: 18
                text_size: root.width-20, 20
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1

            TextInput:
                id: password
                multiline:False
                password:True
                font_size: 28

        Button:
            text: 'Connect'
            font_size: 24
            on_release: app.root.current = "poverview"



<PortfolioOverview>:
    name: "poverview"
    MenuFloatLayout:

<Portfolio>:
    name: "portfolio"
    MenuFloatLayout:

<Market>:
    name: "market"
    MenuFloatLayout:

<Economics>:
    name: "economics"
    MenuFloatLayout:

<PortfolioTools>:
    name: "ptools"
    MenuFloatLayout:
```

Goal is to either link my custom widget back to my screen manager or find an easier solution to link the toggle buttons state to the current screen.

AttributeError: 'MenuFloatLayout' object has no attribute 'manager'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make your root widget a Layout widget (`GridLayout`, `BoxLayout`, or `FloatLayout`), and have your screen manager take up only part of the actual screen. Try changing

```
WindowManager:
    StartWindow:
    PortfolioOverview:
    Portfolio:
```

to:

```
GridLayout:
    # Play with using a FloatLayout or BoxLayout instead of GridLayout if you want
    cols: 1
    MenuFloatLayout:
        id: the_menu_id
    WindowManager:
        StartWindow:
        PortfolioOverview:
        Portfolio:
```

That way your menu will persist and the screen manager is only changing part of the actual screen.

By giving the `MenuFloatLayout` an `id` you are able to reference it. To reference it from the Python side, use `self.root.ids.the_menu_id` if you're referencing it from your `App` object. If you're in some other kind of object, you can do the same by first importing `App` (`import App`) and then using `App.get_running_app().root.ids.the_menu_id`

To reference it from your screens, you can use the `app` keyword. For example: `app.root.ids.the_menu_id`

All three ways of referencing the menu's `id` are essentially identical.

Answer (score 0):

## Problems

- Too many instances of `MenuFloatLayout`
- Use lots of resources e.g. memory, this makes the app big and poor performance

### Solution

- Create one instance of `MenuFloatLayout`
- Each screen reference the one and only one instance of `MenuFloatLayout`
- Use nested [`ScreenManager`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html). This first `ScreenManager` for controlling the authentication / login screen. The second `ScreenManager` for navigation between different screens.
- Create a [dynamic class](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes) for `ToggleButton`

### Example

#### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class StartWindow(Screen):
    pass


class PortfolioOverview(Screen):
    pass


class Portfolio(Screen):
    pass


class Market(Screen):
    pass


class Economics(Screen):
    pass


class PortfolioTools(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

#### main.kv - kv file

```
<WindowManager>:
    sm2: sm2
    StartWindow:
    Screen:
        name: 'connect'

        ScreenManager:
            id: sm2
            PortfolioOverview:
            Portfolio:
            Market:
            Economics:
            PortfolioTools:

        MenuFloatLayout:


<CustomToggleButton@ToggleButton>:    # dynamic class
    group: "pmenu"
    state: "normal" if app.root is None else "down" if app.root.sm2.current == self.text.lower() else "normal"

    background_disabled_down: "atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_pressed"
    disabled_color: 1, 1, 1, 1

    on_state:
        if self.state == "down": self.disabled = True
        else: self.disabled = False

    on_release:
        app.root.sm2.current = self.text.lower()


<MenuFloatLayout@FloatLayout>:    # dynamic class
    Label:
        text: "Portfolio"
        markup: True
        size_hint: 0.5, None
        height: 30
        pos_hint:{"top":1, "left":1}

    TextInput:
        hint_text: "Search"
        multiline: False
        size_hint: 0.5, None
        height: 30
        pos_hint:{"top":1, "right":1}

    ScrollView:
        size_hint: None, None
        do_scroll_y: False
        do_scroll_x: True
        size: 500, 150

        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            size_hint_y: None

            CustomToggleButton:
                text: 'Overview'
                state: 'down'   # default

            CustomToggleButton:
                text: 'Portfolio'

            CustomToggleButton:
                text: 'Market'

            CustomToggleButton:
                text: 'Economics'

            CustomToggleButton:
                text: 'Tools'


<StartWindow>:
    name: "start"
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
        color: 1, 1, 1, 0
        id: login_layout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [10,10,10,10]
        spacing: 30

        Label:
            text: 'some text'
            font_size: 32
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Label:
                text: 'Login'
                font_size: 18
                halign: 'left'
                text_size: root.width-20, 20
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1

            TextInput:
                id: login
                multiline:False
                font_size: 28

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: 'Password'
                halign: 'left'
                font_size: 18
                text_size: root.width-20, 20
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1

            TextInput:
                id: password
                multiline:False
                password:True
                font_size: 28

        Button:
            text: 'Connect'
            font_size: 24
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = 'connect'



<PortfolioOverview>:
    name: "overview"
    Label:
        text: 'Screen - Overview'

<Portfolio>:
    name: "portfolio"
    Label:
        text: 'Screen - Portfolio'

<Market>:
    name: "market"
    Label:
        text: 'Screen - Market'

<Economics>:
    name: "economics"
    Label:
        text: 'Screen - Economics'

<PortfolioTools>:
    name: "tools"
    Label:
        text: 'Screen - Portfolio Tools'
```

### Output

[image: Result]

Comment: Maybe this was running with an older version of Kivy, but with Kivy 2.1.0 I can't get it to work - just a black screen. And: I don't understand why!? Would you please check your code against newest Kivy-Version?